# View a json-object in angular 5

Tags: angular

I get a json-response from a symfony-controller:

In the controller it looks so:

```
$json = json_encode($arrTank);
return new response($json, 200);
```

The jsonstring looks like this:

> [{"obn":"1637","tsnummer":"87","tsname":"xxxx","tsort":"xxx","letztesDatum":"2018-03-13 02:00:00","produkte":[{"bezeichnung":"E10","artikelnummer":"2","tanknummer":"4","tankgroesse":"19005","aktuellerStand":"8250","eintag":"8450","dreitage":"8850","siebentage":null},{"bezeichnung":"SP 95","artikelnummer":"4","tanknummer":"1","tankgroesse":"19005","aktuellerStand":"12412","eintag":"13612","dreitage":"14012","siebentage":null},{"bezeichnung":"DK","artikelnummer":"5","tanknummer":"5","tankgroesse":"9500","aktuellerStand":"5045","eintag":"5145","dreitage":"5445","siebentage":null},{"bezeichnung":"DK","artikelnummer":"5","tanknummer":"2","tankgroesse":"28501","aktuellerStand":"15092","eintag":"15292","dreitage":"15692","siebentage":null},{"bezeichnung":"VP Racing","artikelnummer":"13","tanknummer":"3","tankgroesse":"9720","aktuellerStand":"1813","eintag":"2113","dreitage":"2513","siebentage":null}]},{"obn":"2113","tsnummer":"84","tsname":"xxx","tsort":"xxx","letztesDatum":"2018-03-13 02:00:00","produkte":[{"bezeichnung":"E10","artikelnummer":"2","tanknummer":"4","tankgroesse":"19005","aktuellerStand":"925000","eintag":"845000","dreitage":"885000","siebentage":null},{"bezeichnung":"SP 95","artikelnummer":"4","tanknummer":"1","tankgroesse":"19005","aktuellerStand":"1441200","eintag":"1361200","dreitage":"1401200","siebentage":null},{"bezeichnung":"DK","artikelnummer":"5","tanknummer":"5","tankgroesse":"9500","aktuellerStand":"584500","eintag":"514500","dreitage":"544500","siebentage":null},{"bezeichnung":"DK","artikelnummer":"5","tanknummer":"2","tankgroesse":"28501","aktuellerStand":"1609200","eintag":"1529200","dreitage":"1569200","siebentage":null},{"bezeichnung":"VP Racing","artikelnummer":"13","tanknummer":"3","tankgroesse":"9720","aktuellerStand":"291300","eintag":"211300","dreitage":"251300","siebentage":null}]}]

When I put this string direct in the typescript like

jsonString: string = "herethe string from above";

then it works fine without any error.

But when I try to use it direct from the url with the following script, the data would be viewed, but I got also a error in the console

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-start',
    templateUrl: './start.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./start.component.scss']
})
export class StartComponent implements OnInit {

    objekte: any;
    serverUrl = 'http://url/url';

    constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.objekte = this.http.get(this.serverUrl)
            .subscribe(data => this.objekte = data);

        this.http.get(this.serverUrl)
            .subscribe(
                function(data) {
                    this.test = data;
                    console.log(data);
                }
            )

        console.log(this.objekte);
    }

}
```

> StartComponent.html:5 ERROR Error: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.

When I print both at the same time in the console, then both objects look excatly the same (the remote one and an the one in the string.

Where is my mistake?

Here is the html:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="card-columns">
    <div class="card" *ngFor="let objekt of objekte">
        <div class="card-header">
            {{ objekt.obn }} -
            {{ objekt.tsnummer }} -
            {{ objekt.tsname }} -
            {{ objekt.tsort }}
            <small>Stand: {{ objekt.letztesDatum }} Uhr</small>
        </div>
        <div class="card-body">
            <div class="app-table-responsive">
                <table class="table table-hover">
                    <th colspan="2">Produkt</th>
                    <th>Tankgröße
                    <th>Aktuell</th>
                    <th>-1</th>
                    <th>-3</th>
                    <th>-7</th>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr *ngFor="let produkt of objekt.produkte">
                            <td>{{ produkt.bezeichnung }}</td>
                            <td>{{ produkt.artikel }}</td>
                            <td>{{ produkt.tankgroesse }}</td>
                            <td>{{ produkt.aktuellerStand }}</td>
                            <td>{{ produkt.eintag }}</td>
                            <td>{{ produkt.dreitage }}</td>
                            <td>{{ produkt.siebentage }}</td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't put the subscription to your `objekte` field. This may be the solution.

It will be even better if you implement the `OnDestroy` to release the `this.sub`

```
import {
  Component,
  OnInit
} from '@angular/core';
import {
  HttpClient
} from '@angular/common/http';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-start',
  templateUrl: './start.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./start.component.scss']
})
export class StartComponent implements OnInit {

  objekte: any;
  sub: any;
  serverUrl = 'http://url/url';

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.sub = this.http.get(this.serverUrl)
      .subscribe(data => this.objekte = data);

    this.http.get(this.serverUrl)
      .subscribe(
        function(data) {
          this.test = data;
          console.log(data);
        }
      )

    console.log(this.objekte);
  }

}
```